# Android: can I change the price of an in app purchase consumable?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I need to change the price of our in app product (consumable) for Android - seems pretty easy in the console, but I found the following statement in the documentation (https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview#in-app-product-configuration-options):

```
Warning: You cannot change the price of an in-app product after you make it available for purchase.
```

But if that's the case, how can I change the price? If I need to make a new product, then users not updating the app still get the old price... What am I missing here?

Comment: That warning is very confusing and I'd suggest wrong.  Maybe they mean you cannot change pricing type from one time purchase to subscription which is the case.
I have products live and tweak prices via the console all the time for limited time sales etc.

Comment: thanks, @CodeChimp - "tweak prices all the time" means NO new build, right? And I guess your prices are not only going down but sometimes up again? :)

Comment: correct, no new build.  Just update via the play console.  I tweak pricing up and down, there's no restriction.

Comment: last question: do you know if it's possible to schedule a price change like it's possible for iOS?

Comment: I don't believe so, I've never seen an option to schedule that.  Only app releases.